# where is the data store when i using google-app-engine on localhost

Tags: google-app-engine

i want to find the data on my disk

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

usually the datastore is stored in a file in your system temporary folder (with filename dev_appserver.datastore). You can explicitly tell the devappserver to store the data somewhere else with the `--datastore_path` option [Using the Datastore](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver.html#Using_the_Datastore)